# How to read binary file place in server?

Tags: android, arrays, bytebuffer

I want to read binary file that is placed in server. what i want is data should be placed in bytearray.

Following is my piece of code:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(uurl.openStream()));

String str;
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    text_file=text_file+str;
    text_file=text_file+"\n";
}
m_byteVertexBuffer=text_file.getBytes();
```

But i am not getting correct result

Comment: WHats the o/p u are getting ? Any exception ?

Comment: Your approach isn't very fast and too complicated. Better read the bytes in a buffer and put the chunks in a ByteArrayOutputStream

Comment: i am not getting any exception but i am not getting correct resukt

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (it reads an image, but could modified to read generic binaries)

```
        aURL = new URL(imageUrl);
        URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
        InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream()); 
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        is = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream()); 
        bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is, null, options); 
        is.close();
```

Comment: what is bm in this case